# Complex Variables Transformations

Tags: complex-analysis

Just working through a question on transformations but needed some clarification on something. I understand that here we use $f(x,y)=u(x,y) +iv(x,y)$ and I also got $x^2$-$y^2$ for my $x$ value, but I am unsure how we obtain the $y$ value of $2xy$. Could anyone help me on this please?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If $z=x+iy,$ then $$z^2=(x+iy)(x+iy)=x^2+2ixy-y^2=(x^2-y^2)+i(2xy).$$ So, $(x,y)\mapsto (x^2-y^2, 2xy).$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You/re welcome!